# Freeing/destroying a singly linked list with a for loop

Tags: c

I know it is possible to free a singly linked list like below:

```
void freeList(struct n** head)
{
   struct n* tmp;

   while (*head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = *head;
       *head = (*head)->next;
       free(tmp);
    }
   
   *head = NULL;
}
```

The above code works perfectly and can be said to be simple enough for its purpose. Is it, however, possible to achieve the same with a for loop instead of a while loop? I have tried alot of quirks but don't seem to getting anywhere.

Comment: Any C `while` loop can be trivially rewritten as a `for` loop with empty initialization and increment clauses.

Comment: You could in theory, also write a `goto` loop. But that is not recommended. Also a recursive function can be used.

Comment: It's a shame you didn't show us some of your quirks, otherwise we could have explained what's wrong with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways, for example:

```
void freeList(struct n** head)
{
   for(struct n *tmp = *head; tmp; tmp = *head) {
   {
       *head = tmp->next;
       free(tmp);
   }
}
```

However, your while loop is (arguably) easier to read and understand, though it can be simplified:

```
void freeList(struct n** head)
{
   // moving struct n* tmp to smallest possible scope, in the loop

   while (*head != NULL)
    {
       struct n *tmp = *head;
       *head = tmp->next;
       free(tmp);
    }
   
   // removing *head = NULL because while loop end condition already guarantees this
}
```